# sql php insert in to table via if statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, variables

simply put my code doesn't seem to be working probably the variables work and echo out its simply the code for insert im doing wrong no error just doesnt insert into the table.. the idea is that it inserts in to a table and replaces the data already in the id selected

```
if(($_REQUEST['questionbox']=="" )||($_REQUEST['boxA']=="")|| ($_REQUEST['boxB']=="")|| ($_REQUEST['boxC']=="")|| ($_REQUEST['boxD']=="")|| ($_REQUEST['correctbox']==""))
{
echo "must enter data";
}else{
 $sql2 = "INSERT INTO `tblas`(`id`, `question`, `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `correct`) VALUES ([".$idbox."],[".$questionbox."],[".$boxA."],[".$boxB."],[".$boxC."],[".$boxD."],[".$correctbox."])";
$editquery= mysql_query($sql2, $db);
echo $editquery;
```

Comment: You want to insert or update the row?

Comment: u need to write query for UPDATE if u want to replace contents from old ID

Comment: You can use the UPDATE action as already mentioned. You can also use the REPLACE INTO action http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Comment: well that would make a difference, looking over examples how would I do this with my code? dont have to write it out just if you could show an example with my code so far I am thinking something like
"UPDATE tblas SET question =$questionbox, A=$boxA WHERE id=$idbox";
would that be it? or am i far off?

Comment: Thank you guys for the help and yeah update worked perfectly, can't believe i didnt stumble upon that earlier!!! 

Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this query instead of insert query

```
if(($_REQUEST['questionbox']=="" )||($_REQUEST['boxA']=="")|| ($_REQUEST['boxB']=="")|| ($_REQUEST['boxC']=="")|| ($_REQUEST['boxD']=="")|| ($_REQUEST['correctbox']==""))
{   
    echo "must enter data";
}else{
    $sql2 = "UPDATE tblas SET id='".$idbox."', question = '".$questionbox."', A = '".$boxA."', B = '".$boxB."' ,C = '".$boxC."', D= '".$boxD."' , correct= '".$correctbox."'";
}

echo $editquery;
```

Comment: added where id=$idbox and it worked perfectly thank you so much!!